# Weird Assignment IDE Warning

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, user-interface, canvas

I'm currently developing an html5 canvas application.
It's also required to work on mobile devices.
One of the features is a bmi calculation like this:

Javascript code:

```
bmi = refweight / ((refheight/ 100)*(refheight/ 100)) ;
```

Netbeans (7.3) gives me a warning, saying: "Weird assingnment"

I know that I can use `Math.pow();` here, but any alteratinos to the code breaks all the code on mobile devices.

Is there a proper way to do that?

BTW, the formula for BMI is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4ooa.gif

Comment: Possibly related to https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227046

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bug (which I believe is fixed by now in version 8).

A weird assignment hint appears when the developer writes a code that looks like this:

```
x = x;
```

As you can see, the code is unnecessary and doesn't change anything.